# PDO select like query for only match numeric value

Tags: php, mysql

I have one query and I have one table and its field name is `contact_number` its datatype is `var-char` and its values

```
 `e.g  (123) 145-4488, (544) 854-5845, (456) 445-6452.`
```

Now I want to make search query and the search input will be like `1231454488, 5448545845, 4564456452` then how will I do query for get me better result.
Is it possible?

Comment: you are doing wrong. you should save your contact_number value as for ex: 1231454488. and when you have to display it in your page you should use php function for formatting.

Comment: You should simply store your phone numbers into your database like so (1231454488, 5448545845, 4564456452). Make the field a CHAR(10) with an index and you'll be rockin. It's much easier to just format these phone numbers coming out of the database as well to any format you like.

Comment: storing phone number as this format 1231454488 is not possible because i have many files and my db is too large. And its CRM project so I think you can better understand for change in this format may be create big issue

Comment: Then what if user type '123'? Will the query you want return any result?

Comment: yes if i write this query SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE contact_number LIKE '%123%' then it will return result but for this its not working SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE contact_number LIKE '%1231% @Forward

Comment: If your format is consistent just transform your search term to match that format, e.g. `$s = "(".substr($q,0,3).") ".substr($q,3,3)."-".substr($q,6)`, though as suggested, you will need to actually flatten the numbers when you insert and format them when displaying. Databases should not be concerned with presentation aspects of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your contact number in db is fixed format like :`(XXX) XXX-XXXX`, you just need replace these symbol to empty string.

```
select *
from yourtable
where replace(replace(replace(replace(contact_number, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') like '%$some_input_value%'
```

Seems to be a very violent ugly way, but may work.

Comment: not working getting error `syntax error, unexpected '(' in`

Comment: @RushilPachchigar See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/925b9/1) here, the syntax should be correct, is there any other wrong place in your code?